# What's the difference between a protocol and API?

Tags: xorg, opengl, wayland, mesa, vulkan

I was wondering what is the difference between a protocol and API in Linux? What makes X11 and Wayland a protocol meanwhile OpenGL and Vulkan are APIs?

Comment: You may also like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250443/what-is-the-difference-between-internet-api-and-internet-protocols).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API are used to programmer and they're classes or functions that a programmer can use to build applications.

A protocol is all that rules that are used to do somethings. Some examples of protocols are: http and https (for the web browser), ftp (for client ftp), imap/pop/smtp (these are three protocols for mail server), telnet/ssh (are protocols to connect to remote server to use it by command line), dns (this is used to convert the name of a site to its ip), irc (this protocol is used for old style chat), rdp (means remote desktop protocol, and it has used by windows to connect to other windows machine and use its graphical interface), and so on.

PS. the op has changed the question after my answer.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Does this mean stuff like xlib and XCB count as an API and what makes an API different from a library?

Comment: in my opinion more or less they are the same.. maybe the library is the container and api it's more formal and abstract word. The word api means Application Programming Interface.. then it's an interface to the library.